# Vue app has compilation error when serve is run from jest-playwright-preset, but works fine otherwise

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, jestjs, playwright

I'm trying to test a vue.js application with playwright.
If I start the mocked server with `npm run serve:mock` from the command line, then run playwright using `npm run test:playwright` (jest -c jest-playwright.config.js), everything works fine.

If I try to combine both and have the server start from jest-playwright-preset (jest-process-manager), I get compilation errors when the development server starts:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (139:76) File was processed with
> these loaders:  * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js  *
> ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js  *
> ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js You may need an additional
> loader to handle the result of these loaders.

This is the jest-playwright.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    rootDir: '.',
    testTimeout: 120000,
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>/tests/playwright/*.spec.js'],
    preset: 'jest-playwright-preset',
    testEnvironmentOptions: {
        'jest-playwright': {
            launchOptions: {
                headless: false
            },
            contextOptions: {
                ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
                bypassCSP: true
            },
            browsers: ['chromium', 'firefox']
        }
    },
    serverOptions: {
        command: 'npm run serve:mock',
        launchTimeout: 50000,
        port: 8080,
        debug: true
    }
};
```

Why is there a difference, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Was you able to fix it? Have the same problem right now

Comment: Unfortunately not...
According to jest documentation, webpack project need moduleNameMapper configured for loaders. 
I can't just seem to figure out which mapper I'm missing for my Vue project